# Xamarin Forms Grid - change cell view via button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page in which I display two different charts, depending on a button click. At the moment I change charts this way:

```
    protected void ClickedChangeChart()
    {
        if (chartType == true) 
        {
            chartType = false;
            Navigation.PushAsync (new MainPage (false));
        } 

        else 
        {
            chartType = true;
            Navigation.PushAsync (new MainPage (true));
        }
    }
```

chartType is a bool and depending on it's value I choose which chart to load using this statement in OnAppearing():

```
protected override async void OnAppearing ()
{
// some code
    ChartView chartView = new ChartView 
    { 
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, 
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    HeightRequest = 300,
    WidthRequest = 400
    }; 

    if (chartType == true)//true = candle
    { 
        candleModel = new CandleModel ();
        chartView.Model = await candleModel.GetModel ();
    } 

    else if(chartType == false) //false = line
    {
        lineModel = new LineModel ();
        chartView.Model = await lineModel.GetModel ();
    }

    //here I create a grid, add some children to it and the add the chartView
    grid.Children.Add (chartView, 1, 6, 1, 3);

    Content = grid;
}
```

The problem is that when I want to switch the charts I have to reload the whole page, which isn't what I want. How can I make it so when I click a button I calls a function which switches the model for the chart? I suppose it will be something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
    public async void ClickedButton()
    {
        grid.Children.Remove(chartView);

        if (chartType == true)
        { 
            candleModel = new CandleModel ();
            chartView.Model = await candleModel.GetModel ();
        } 

        else if(chartType == false)
        {
            lineModel = new LineModel ();
            chartView.Model = await lineModel.GetModel ();
        }
        grid.Children.Add(chartView);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Using Daniel Luberda's solution, I managed to get it to work with this:

```
btnChartType.Clicked += async delegate {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {
        grid.Children.Remove (chartView);

        if (isCandle == true) { 
            candleModel = new CandleModel ();
            chartView.Model = await candleModel.GetModel ();
            isCandle = false;
        } else if (isCandle == false) {
            lineModel = new LineModel ();
            chartView.Model = await lineModel.GetModel ();
            isCandle = true;
        }
                grid.Children.Add (chartView, 1, 6, 1, 3); 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get it to work because you have an async method which means that you're doing it on another thread. You can change UI only from UI thread. Also `async void` will swallow all exceptions, it's better to use `async Task` instead.

```net
// THAT WILL WORK

public async void ClickedButton() // but public async Task would be better
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        grid.Children.Remove(chartView);

        if (chartType == true)
        { 
            candleModel = new CandleModel ();
            chartView.Model = await candleModel.GetModel ();
        } 

        else if(chartType == false)
        {
            lineModel = new LineModel ();
            chartView.Model = await lineModel.GetModel ();
        }
        grid.Children.Add(chartView);   
    });
}
```

Comment: The first method doesn't work because there are await calls and ClickedButton isn't async, and when I make it async it still doesn't work.
The second method doesn't work because when I call it with `Command = new Command (ClickedButton)`, I get the error: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task MyProject.MainPage.ClickedButton() has the wrong return type`.

Comment: I edited my response. Didn't notice `await` calls. Just change `Task` to `void`, but I would strongly recommend to use `async Task` instead of `async void` for future.

Comment: It compiles, but still doesn't work. This time when I call it, I get java.lang.reflect.IncovationTargetException when I click the button. :(

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code. It could be anything. We need more info (Source, StackTrace)